# System.OutOfMemoryException thrown after reading 4000 files

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

We want to import 52000 files (`.pdf`, `.xls`, `.doc` ...etc) into a SQL Server 2012 database.

I have a `Dossier_fichier.txt` file that contain the file's names. I load those names into a collection and I loop over this collection and I try to find those files in direcotry `PiecesJointes` and to convert them to bytes and insert them into the database with this code:

```
var dossierFichiers = addOrUpdateHelper.ReadEntities<DossierFichier, DossierFichierMap>("dossier_fichier.txt").ToArray();
// (2) Parcourir toutes les instances de DossierFichier chargées + Lire le fichier référencé + Le charger dans la propriété Fichier
var dirPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "piecesJointes");
var nbfichier = 0;

foreach (var df in dossierFichiers) {
    try {
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirPath, string.Concat( df.Code,"_", df.Nom));
        df.Fichier = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        context.DossierFichier.Add(df);
        context.SaveChanges();

        Logger.Info("Le fichier {0} a été inséré", df.Nom);

        nbfichier++;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.Error("Fichier {0} : {1}", df.Nom, ex.Message);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.Error("Fichier {0} : {1}",df.Nom, ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I get an `OutOFMemoryException` after inserting 4000 files and it took a lot of time (60 hours). Please could you help me to insert all those files without getting `OutOfmemoryException`, and how to do it faster?

Comment: Your system will not have infinite memory, you may need to periodically save the data out and then dispose of it. Or even read one file do what you need to do then remove it from memory.

Comment: how can i dispoe it? how can i remove it from memory

Comment: Is that running in 32-bit process? Also, better create new Entity Framework context for _every_ insert, and load each entity separately, don't reuse context and entities.

Comment: Without knowing what `DossierFichier` I have no idea. It depends why you need the files bytes. If your just reading the bytes and storing them somewhere my answer will be to different to if you need all of the memory for the length of the program.

Comment: As a side note: Reading 52k files is gonna take some time. Just as it is. Out of curiosity, what's the average size of the files?

Comment: Your DbContext is probably caching a whole bunch of stuff that you don't need any more. You'll need to let go of it and dispose it every once in a while. You should also consider https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj556205.aspx

Comment: 64 bit process. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk

Comment: yes i' am just reading and inserting files and DB , that's all i need

Comment: I added a DbContext for each file but i still have outofmemory exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your code has O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance because it keeps all file contents in memory.

- First iteration of the loop saves the first object that you added
- Second iteration saves the second object and refreshes the first object
- Third iteration saves the third object and refreshes the first two objects
- ... and so on
- N-th iteration inserts N-th object, and refreshes previously inserted N-1 objects

You should be able to fix this by "batching" the updates together:

- Add a count of how many objects you have inserted so far
- Do not call `context.SaveChanges();` right away
- When the number of inserted objects reaches, say, 100, call `context.SaveChanges();`, and then replace `context` with a new instance.

This will ensure that all objects are saved only once, that the number of round-trips to the database stays under control, and that you never have more than 100 objects in memory.

In addition, you keep the content of the file around by sticking it into `df.Fichier`. This has a potential of running your system out of memory, so you should copy `df` instead:

```
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirPath, string.Concat( df.Code,"_", df.Nom));
var dfCopy = new DossierFichier(df); // Copy df's fields
dfCopy.Fichier = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
context.DossierFichier.Add(dfCopy);
```

Comment: Or just create new context for every update, usually works fine too.

Comment: You should probably make a note about keeping the bytes in memory too i.e. `df.Fichier = File.ReadAllBytes(path);` Even with the update you describe there is still a possibility of out of memory due to all those bytes being in memory.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder You are right, I did not realize that the content was saved in the loop variable's `Fichier` field. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: I added a DbContext for each file but i still have outofmemory exception

Comment: @amina The trick is to make sure that `DbContext`s for prior files get discarded when you no longer need them, and that you set `df.Fichier = null` once the call `context.SaveChanges()` has successfully returned.

Comment: it is ok , it work fine , thank you @dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 1):

For each item in the collection, you add the whole file contents (the array of bytes) to `df.Fichier`. This is one of the reasons the memory usage is increasing.

You can resolve this particular issue by using a temporary variable.

Comment: How can i free memory after creating byte ?

Comment: I added a DbContext for each file but i still have outofmemory exception

Comment: @Evk    
I added a DbContext for each file but i still have outofmemory exception